# How to obtain a character from KeyboardEvent.code based on the current layout?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I’m making a rhythm game, and I want the players to be able to play with whatever keys they want. Their choice should be stored into their account so that they can log in *anywhere* and play with the same keys, or change them. The thing is, that includes other keyboard layouts.

What matters in this case is the location of the key, not the character it prints, so I’m thinking of storing the [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) attribute from the relevant `KeyboardEvent`s, but the character is a much easier way to present the saved keys back to the user in case they need a reminder.

So I have a physical key code and a user that could be using any keyboard layout. Is it possible to find out the corresponding character (or [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) value), and if so, how?

Quasi-solutions:

1. Have the user type that key and check the resulting `KeyboardEvent`: Since the character could be used as a reminder, this doesn’t solve the problem.
2. Store the character in database: The keyboard layout used to set the playing keys isn’t necessarily the one used to play. If `Q` is set as the character and `KeyQ` as the `code`, when playing on a French keyboard, the player will be told to use Q but the game will actually expect A.
3. Dispatch a `KeyboardEvent` with the right `code`: Unfortunately, the browser doesn’t fill up the missing properties, so we don’t get the character.

Comment: I can tell you, this is a nightmare-ish job to do. Issues mostly being with the storing of the character, mainly because the event doesnt distinguish between Q and q, its based on the keycode, in other words, no modifiers allowed. Now, you can only do this if you store the code itself, if you attempt to store a character, all hell breaks loose. Still doable but highly un-recommended, as you would be circumventing the design of a key being a key not a letter it prints.

Comment: Indeed. I’m going to store the key code because the character is irrelevant anyway, but I need a way to tell the user what key they should press, and the way I’d like to do that is by showing them the character associated to that key on their current keyboard.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

Comment: No, what I have is a key code (basically a location on the keyboard), not a char code. The user keyboard layout needs to be involved in some way to get the right character, but I don’t know how…

Comment: To my knowledge (which is limited, mind you) there is no way to convert a keycode to a charcode based on the layout. If there were the events wouldn't be sending both of them upon being triggered. I stored the keycode and the charcode separatly though obviously this doesn't work if the user changes layouts. You can as an alternative just do everything with character codes.... but that is bad as I said earlier

Comment: Well, I guess I’ll use a more visual representation, like highlighting the selected keys on a keyboard picture or something… Thanks for your replies!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bb5v9cx6/  This is the closest to a solution i can get you.